# Imprecise pulse width capture using Atmel SAM D51

Tags: arm, embedded, microchip, atmel, sam

We are using an ATSAMD51P19A and the Timer/Counter for Control Applications (TCC) to detect the pulse width from the assertion of a pin to the detection of a signal on another pin, and are having trouble achieving our desired resolution of +/- 10 nsec.

The below block diagram shows our Atmel START configuration to capture the pulse width.

[image]

Using a delay generator, we know the time delta from the assertion of the pin PA23 to the rising edge of the pin PA22 is 720 nsec +/- 5 nsec.   Given our configuration, we expect that we should capture a pulse width of 720 nsec +/- 10 nsec.  However, we are seeing 720 nsec +/- 50 nsec.   Our application requires +/- 10 nsec, so the +/- 50 nsec is undesirable.

We have tried many configurations and have been unable to achieve an accuracy of less than +/- 50 nsec.  Any suggestions or feedback on how to achieve a higher resolution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not very clear.  Rather than your unconventional "block diagram", a hardware schematic and the code would serve you better w.r.t. getting an answer.  Also you say "we know" the time period, but how do you know?  Is this some specific piece or certified calibrated test equipment or something you have built yourself?  Have you verified the precision with an oscilloscope.  Also I am confused by tour term "pulse width".  A pulse is a signal on a single line, you appear to be measuring the interval between two separate signals 0 is that the case?

Comment: it is hard to tell from your "diagram", but it seems you are starting a counter from one pin, then reading the counter in an interrupt handler for a different pin.  There will be an overhead for the interrupt handling and the interrupt may be delayed by other interrupts or is interrupts are temporarily disabled.  You would do better to trigger the counter start and stop in hardware to accurately measure a period so that there is no software overhead or interrupt preemption or delay.

Comment: The code is autogenerated from Atmel START,  hence the screenshots and blocks.

We know the time period because we are using a calibrated delay generator, and we have verified the delay with an oscilloscope.

You're right, we are overloading the term pulse width.  For our application needs, I am defining it as the time from the rising edge of an output to the rising edge of an input.  

Because we are using the TCC, we have no code involved except for the initial event and then the reading of the count.  As best we can tell, we have eliminated any unnecessary CPU involvment.

Comment: Since there is no code of your own and just TCC configuration perhaps it is not a question for SO but rather https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks.  I'll do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved our own issue.

The root cause of our problem was an oscillation on the `MCU_VDDCORE/MCC_VSW` supply rails of the ATSAMD51P19A, which was caused by the the low capacitor  value connected to the `MCU_VDDCORE/MCU_VSW` circuit.

By adding a larger capacitor to the `MCU_VDDCORE/MCU_VSW` circuit, we removed the oscillation, which in turn solved our timing issue.  Our variance went from +/- 50 nsec to +/- 10 nsec.